# live migration on ubuntu llucid lynx

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, migration, kvm-virtualization

I tried do live migration from ubuntu lucid lynx machine 1, to ubuntu lucid lynx machine 2. The name of vm is VM3jasmine I and would like to migrate to machine2
when i enter a command, (from machine1)

```
#vrsh migrate --live VM3jasmine qemu+ssh://machine2@192.168.0.50/system,
```

i got error ,

```
qemu: could not open disk image /var/lib/libvirt/images/VM3jasmine.img: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

where is the VM image located? It should be accessible to both machines, in a centrally managed storage domain. otherwise, the destination host will not be able to start the migrating VM because it cannot find it's disk image

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, support for live migration between hosts that do not share storage was added to qemu-kvm release 0.12.1 and libvirt started supporting that since 0.8.2.  Lucid's versions are older than that, but there are backports in PPAs.